# Proving that the Dimension of Eigenspace Is 1

Tags: linear-algebra

The following was taken by Stephen Friedberg's Linear Algebra, Thereom 5.23 and Corollary 1.

Let $A \in M_{n x n} ( \mathbb C)$ be such that each entry $a_{ij} \in \mathbb R^+$.  $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ such that $|\lambda| = \rho(A)$, the row sum of $A$.  So:

$$\rho(A) = \max_{i \le n} \left\{ \ \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}| \ \right\}$$

Thereom 5.23 showed that we will have a stronger statement that $\lambda = \rho(A)$.  Moreover, the eigenspace of $\lambda$ is spanned by $u = (1, 1 \ldots 1)^t$.  Now, we're asked to show that for the same matrix $A$, if the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ is such that $|\lambda| = \nu(A)$, the column sum, then $\lambda = \nu(A)$ and its eigenspace has dimension $1$.  For clarity:

$$\nu(A) = \max_{j \le n} \left\{ \ \sum_{i=1}^n |a_{ij}| \ \right\}$$

By examining $A^t$ we can apply Theorem 5.23 and say that $\lambda = \rho(A^t) = \nu(A)$.  However, what is the relationship between the eigenspace of $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue of $A$, and the eigenspace of the same $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue of $A^t$?

Comment: It has something to do with the more general  Perron-Frobenius Theorem [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) If you claim that $(1,1,\ldots,1)^t$ is an eigenvector then the sum in each row is the same. You should skip absolute values as you assume that $a_{ij}$ are positive.

Comment: Never mind ...  I overcomplicated things.  It's just rank-nullity.  $dim N(A - \lambda I) = dim N(A^t - \lambda I)$.